# Как развернуть Django веб-приложение на сервер с lighttpd FastCGI и Virtual Hosts?

Tags: развертывание, virtual-hosts, lighttpd, fastcgi, django

Как развернуть Django веб-приложение на сервер с lighttpd FastCGI и Virtual Hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя Virual Hosts это не получится.